# Select data from one data source and store it in another

Tags: mysql, r, db2, rmysql

I am using RODBCext to create a parameter query to retrieve data from a DB2 mainframe.  I want to insert that data into a table in a local MYSQL (on the  same network) to be able to access the data much more  quickly and on the fly with a Shiny app.  i am not sure how to do that.  The below sql works to retrieve my db2 data, but i cant find help learning how to create the rmysql connection in the same r.script to insert it automatically into the mysql db.  any help, tips or pointers would be appreciated.

```
library(RODBCext)  
library(RMySQL)  
##  
DB2Conn1 <- odbcConnect("dsn", uid = "xxx", pwd = "xxx")  
##################################################################  

plan_id <- paste("Select Field1, Field2 FROM  DB2.Table1 
where Field2 = 'M' ")
```

Comment: Have a look at the `RMySQL` pdf to see how to make the connection. Not very different from RODBC

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I did review that documentation, but i need to somehow simultaneously load the from the db2 environment into mysql because the data is too large to save and then requery into mysql.  Hope that makes sense?

Comment: What is stopping you from using `insert into` commands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked.  I used the `Insert Into` to update the table.  I first had to create the table with the column headers.  Worked fine.  Thanks for your help.